# Optimization: imposing inequality constrains by reparametrizing

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to fit an equation to some data using R's `nls()` function. The function is
$$ \hat{I}(D) = \frac{1}{1 + kD} $$
where values of $D$ are known and the goal is to match observed $I$ values as closely as possible in a least squares sense. I want to impose the constraint $k > 0$, so I have reparametrized $k$ as $k = \text{exp}(x)$. I.e., the equation I am fitting to the data is
$$ \hat{I}(D) = \frac{1}{1 + \text{exp}(x) D} $$
and I can then compute $k$ using the best-fitting value of $x$. Is this approach valid? Is there a name for (and a citation to justify the use of) it?

Comment: Is $I$ a binary variable or numeric?

Comment: @RobertBassett Here $I$ is continuous and is between 0 and 1.